# Функции php для SWF

Tags: php

Есть ролик в формате SWF, как сделать чтобы при загрузке страницы этот ролик раскрывался на всю страницу, а через какое-то время сворачивался в значок.

Answer (score 2):

PHP? Нет, не имеет отношения к php, читайте про javascript.